# Is there a way in Unity3D to detect that a gameobject is on top of a pillarbox in order to avoid rendering it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently developing a 2D Unity game.. At the moment I was able to implement a code that allows the camera to keep the aspect ratio which is initially 16:9 and when the aspect ratio is different it will add the letterbox perfectly. My issue is that I have a HUD that can be hidden by the player, so when I have letterbox implemented the HUD is not hiding properly.. I've spent heaps of time trying to find an answer but I haven't been able to.. Is there a way to avoid rendering/showing the part of the HUD that is on top of the letterbox.? I am attaching an image that shows how the HUD looks normally and how it is being displayed when hidden.. Any help will be greatly appreciated.. Thanks in advance.!

Normal HUD:
[image: how the HUD looks normally]

Hidden HUD:
[image: how the HUD looks when hidden]

Comment: "What is this?  A bouncy castle for ants?!"

Comment: hahahahahahaha.. "Close but no cigar..."

Comment: How can we be expected to teach children to learn how to bounce... if they can't even fit inside the castle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [RectMask2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-RectMask2D.html) component to mask out the letterbox area.  You want to attach the RectMask2D to an object that is a parent of your inventory box.  Children of the RectMask2D will only appear within the area of their parent, so if the mask does not cover the letterbox area, then your inventory bar will not appear over the letterbox either.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed to know.. Thank you very much.!! It worked beautifully.. Cheers mate..